# WP_Query en woocommerce con shortcode API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Buenas tardes necesito mostrar los productos por columnas que arroja una consulta en WP_Query utilizando un shortcode API. La estoy haciendo pero el resultado es una lista de productos en una sola columna y de para abajo me desborda los contenedores. En resumidas cuentas lo que quiero es que pueda mostrar 2 columnas y muestre 2 productos por fila o que le ponga 3 columnas o el numero que quiera y ese sea el numero de productos mostrado por columna.

```html
$atts = shortcode_atts( array (
        'type' => 'product',
        'posts' => '-1',
        'limit' =>  3,
        'category' => '',
        'columns' => 5,
        ), $atts, 'list_products'
   );          
    $loop = new WP_Query(  array(
        
        'post_type' => $atts['type'],
        'posts_per_page' => $atts['posts'],
        'columns'      => $atts['columns'],
        'tax_query' => array( array(

            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $atts['category'],
        )),
        'meta_key' => 'figuranum',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC' 
    
    ));
       if ($loop->have_posts()) {
```

.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class= "columnaintrep">    
                <?php get_template_part( 'content' ); ?>
</div>
```

Para que de pronto alguien le sirva. Utilice un template part y lo meti en el shortcode API lo que hizo que a cada vuelta de bucle buscara y acomodara los productos como yo queria ...(En CSS recomendable usar flexbox la propieadad flex-wrap: wrap; para acomodar mas facil y no desborde el contenido. )